# ThreeJS weird stripes shadow

Tags: javascript, three.js, shadow

I am trying to make room light inside this kitchen http://bozoou.com/plocice3D/
You can notice wierd horizontal strikes of shadow on kitchen element.

I have suspect in spotLight which is in middle of x,y, and top of z axis.
If I move source of light for only 1 point along y-axis (room is 500x300), I got this strikes of shadow on whole floor: http://bozoou.com/plocice3D/?moveLight=1
Same problem happens if I move light for 1 or 50.

All elements cast and receive shadow.

Comment: ow is your floor set up? Is it one large plane or multiple small ones?

Comment: had a nother look at your scene. It does seem like you have overlapping geometry. Meaning yopu have multiple planes at the SAME location. Thus the renderer does not know what to render resulting in this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is usualy caused by the shadow near point is too close to your object. 
For better understanding try to do the follow: 
after you create your light you can add a camera helper to show you the bounderies of the light.

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff, 0.3, 0, Math.PI / 2);
spotLight.position.set(0, 100, 0);
sunLight.castShadow = true;

var shadowCameraHelper = new THREE.CameraHelper(spotLight.shadow.camera);
shadowCameraHelper.visible = true;
```

Kepp changing these two values untile you reach your goal.

```
spotLight.shadow.camera.near = 50;
spotLight.shadow.camera.far = 150;
```

Keep in mind that the more you set spotLight.shadow.camera.far the more that shadow will be fuzzy and blury.

You can always check the threejs on this example
[threejs example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_shading_physical)

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the shadow bias to somethings small and that *sometimes* will alleviate these issues.

```
shadow.bias = 0.0001
```