# THREE.js Diagonal Lines when rendering. showdow.bias helps but not "castShadow" doesn't

Tags: three.js, rendering, shadow

[screen_shot_showing_diagonal_lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S39Pp.png)

My THREE.js project is rendering these **weird diagonal lines**. I searched [online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253464/threejs-weird-stripes-shadow/42978647) and see that the issue is due to **object casting shadow on itself**.

While changing the **shadow.bias property did help**, it also created a gap between the object casting the shadow and the plane receiving the shadow ("**peter-panning**"). *Note the directional light here is the only light source casting shadow in my scene.*

```
this.directionalLight.shadow.bias = -0.001
```

I thought I might resolve this instead by changing the **"castShadow" property of the ground plane meshes to false** in the json file it is reading from so it will not cast shadow on itself but this doesn't seem to change anything in the rendering.

```
"castShadow": false,
"receiveShadow": true
```

I wonder if the shadow casting property is set somewhere else? or perhaps the issue is not with shadows at all (shadow.bias worked so it should be a shadows issue)? or there might be some other way to resolving this.

Thank you!

Comment: Might be the angle of your directional light is too shallow. Have you checked this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63679178/three-js-weird-shadow-artifacts-from-a-spotlight-but-only-in-android#comment112606160_63679178

Comment: Yes I have moved the light around and doesn't seem to change the diagonal lines. But thanks!